# Track the no of days based user assigned dates in sql

Tags: sql

Seems like I got another issue. The solution provided by DAVID P and Toner Mann worked well with some tickets but I do have a different ticket which does not work well with the join assigned_to = Assigned_from. Please check the attached sample data. I would need to find how long any user worked on the ticket. Also, assigned_to and assigned_from cannot be the same as always. [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxtpo.jpg)In the attached scenario James worked on the ticket for 61 days.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: I think you need to search for an algorythm that calculates the difference between dates, Uncle google can help with that.

Comment: @TonnerMààn I think the real issue of the question is more about how to reshape the data so that you can extract just the dates that a particular user was working on a ticket to apply such an algorithm, not how to calculate date differences.

Comment: It seems like I got another issue. The solution provided by DAVID P and Toner Mann worked well with some tickets but I do have a different ticket which does not work well with the join assigned_to = Assigned_from. Please check the attached sample data. I would need to find how long any user worked on the ticket. Also, assigned_to and assigned_from cannot be the same as always. Sample data In the attached scenario James worked on the ticket for 61 days.

Thanks, Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't get good code formatting in a comment, I'm posting this as an answer. This is largely an extension of the answer by Tonner Mààn that rolls some calculations into the query. I tested this query on a local database containing the sample data from the question.

```
SELECT [Ticket],[AssignedTo],SUM([Days]) AS [Duration]
FROM
(
    Select [Ticket],[AssignedTo],
        DATEDIFF(Day, [Date], (Select MIN([Date])
            from [TicketEvents] t2
            where t2.[AssignedFrom] = t1.[AssignedTo]
            AND t2.[Date] >= t1.[Date]
        )) as [Days]
    from [TicketEvents] t1
    where Ticket = '22479-J8C4L3'
    and Status = 'CASE_ASSIGNED'
) AS InnerQuery
GROUP BY [Ticket],[AssignedTo]
```

Result:

```
Ticket        AssignedTo  Duration
22479-J8C4L3  Christine   12
22479-J8C4L3  Phillips    4
22479-J8C4L3  Stacey      8
```

Comment: Yeah this is even better than the improvement i made, it calculates all at once instead of each alone, and it's easy to add one condition if one need only for one person

Comment: Excellent. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much David.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my other comment you need an algorythm that calculates the number of days between two dates, @DavidP noted that you also need a query to extract the dates to apply the algorythm on so here is something that may help:

***Edit:*** Again thanks to @DavidP's idea, here is a code that should be calculating the difference in days:

```
with qry as (
    Select [Ticket],
        [Date] as startDate,
        (Select MIN([Date])
            from [yourTable] t2
            where t2.[Assigned from] = t1.[Assigned to]
            AND t2.[Date] >= t1.[Date]
        ) as endDate
    from [yourTable] t1
    where Ticket = '<value>'
    and [Assigned To] = '<name>'
    and Status = 'CASE_ASSIGNED'
)
select SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,startDate,endDate)) as [Number of days] from qry
```

Obviously I did not test this code but it should <strike>give you the start and end dates to use to</strike> calculate the difference in days.

You may need to add a column with time (hour and minutes) for more precision.

Comment: I threw the sample data into a localDB to test, the query works. You can also extend this by using `DATEDIFF` on the two columns to get the number of days, then wrap the whole thing in a query with `GROUP BY [Assigned To]` so you can get the sum of those duration values in a single query.

Comment: @DavidP Thank you very much for the confirmation, i have some issues on my laptop so i can only test queries when i'm at my office lol. **_Edit:_** was writing my comment during your edit lol, ok i'll give it a try and see if i can come up with something

Comment: Excellent. This also worked for me. Thank you so much Tonner Mààn.